# myObj.forEach(), isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying store a XMLHttpRequest()'s results as a JSon String in an object, The data in the String is several arrays. I'm trying to then read through each array, in myObj.

Obviously, myObj.forEach() doesn't work, because myObj is an object, not an array or a list. How do I make it so I can itterate through myObj, and then use a forEach on each array?

Here is my current code

```
function getFile(){
var input = document.getElementsByName("json")[0];
var filename = input.value;
console.log(filename);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", filename, true);
xhr.send(null); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                  var text = xhr.responseText;
                  document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = "";
                  var myObj = JSON.parse(text);
                  myObj.forEach(function(student) {...});

               }
    }
```

}

Comment: Please post the JSON (or at least the important parts of it)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the keys of the Object into a list using [**Object.keys()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then iterate through them assuming they are all lists:

```
function getFile(){
    var input = document.getElementsByName("json")[0];
    var filename = input.value;
    console.log(filename);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", filename, true);
    xhr.send(null); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var text = xhr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = "";
            var myObj = JSON.parse(text);
            var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                myObj[key].forEach(function(item) {...})
            });
        }
    }
}
```